# ApexCharts don't showing toolbar

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I'm using ApexCharts with React and i'm using a line's chart and it's not showing the toolbar, someone can help me?

[image]

My summed up state of options:

```
const [propriedades, setPropriedades] = useState({
    options: {
        chart: {
            height: 150,
            type: 'line',
            selection: {
                enabled: true
            },
            toolbar: {
                tools: {
                    zoomin: true,
                    zoomout: true,
                }
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        stroke: {
            curve: 'straight'
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: I assume you've tried adding: `toolbar: { show: true, }` to explicitly ask for it (even though it should show by default)?

Comment: I got that issue with a `rangeBar` did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
xaxis: {tickPlacement: "on"},
```

For Angular it was solved by adding this line

Comment: Also works for React JS

Answer (score 1):

just add `xaxis: {tickPlacement: "on" }` in chart property and it will work. it happen to me with javascript. i hope this will help.